# What do you call a person who gets a referral?

Tags: single-word-requests, formality, email

I am applying for a job that my friend has told me about. He spoke with the employer about me and then told me I should send that employer an email. Because this will be is my first contact with the owner, I thought of composing a formal letter.

As the title says, I want to put the subject of my letter as:

> #### Michael’s Referee<sup>(?)</sup>: Job Application

What is the correct word instead of *referee*?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you are the referee of Michael's referral so your suggestion is grammatical. The word "referee," however, is not commonly used in that sense and so may confuse the issue. Why not use the title "Michael X's Referral" to avoid confusion about what Michael you are talking about or whether you are objecting to the referee in some sporting event.